# Removing quotes from the second last slash in a string

Tags: regex, perl

For example, I have a string that is

```
/..../.../hello/hi/bye/try.pl
```

Is there any way I can remove all the quotes from the second last slash character? I'm suppose to get this return string

```
/..../.../hello/hi/
```

I'm hoping to be able to solve this problem using a regex solution.

Comment: Can't understand what you want. Where are the quotes, and what exactly do you want?

Comment: I don't see any quotes to be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your input and your desired output, I guess you're talking about path parts, not quotes.

```
$str =~ s![^/]+/[^/]+$!!;
```

That should work. It's matching from the end of the string ("$") and then just looks for two strings that don't contain a slash with a slash between them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with file systems, it's best to use the standard modules that come with Perl.

```
my $path = '/some/path/hello/hi/bye/try.pl';
print "Original : $path\n";

use File::Basename;
print 'via File::Basename dirname : ', dirname( dirname( $path )), "\n";

use File::Spec::Functions qw( :ALL );
my @path = splitdir( $path );
print 'via File::Spec::Functions splitdir : ', catdir( @path[ 0 .. $#path-2 ] ), "\n";
```